# Center align image in div without changes to parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center align an image in a div. Horizontal alignment is not an issue, but no matter what I try, I can't get the image to center align vertically.
Keep in mind that I am confined to changing the css for the image element, and ideally no changes are required on the parent/containing div as the parent/containing div will also be used for other elements.
Any suggestion would be great.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container style="left: 2ch; top: 3em; width: 15ch; height: 5em;">
   <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to add  `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;`to the container div,

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container style="left: 2ch; top: 3em; width: 15ch; height: 5em;">
   <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
</div>
```

A second option is to change the CSS on the image and use:

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    top: 50%;
    position:relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class=container style="left: 2ch; top: 3em; width: 15ch; height: 5em;">
   <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

j08691 offered a good solution, but if you can't to change parent div, perhaps this will help:

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25%;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container style="left: 2ch; top: 3em; width: 15ch; height: 5em;">
   <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
</div>
```